# Scrappy NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

### I am creating my first spider

I am following and writing code as per in [Scrapy tutorial in docs.scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

> I wrote the below code and saved in C:\Users\DODAAD\scrapy_goodfriday_A01\scrapy_goodfriday_A01\spiders as quotes_spider.py

I have done as per instruction but this error pops up in cmd

```
(base) C:\Users\DODAAD\scrapy_goodfriday_A01>scrapy crawl quotes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 144, in execute
cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 280, in __init__
super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 152, in __init__
self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 146, in _get_spider_loader
return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 68, in from_settings
return cls(settings)
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 24, in __init__
self._load_all_spiders()
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 51, in 
_load_all_spiders
for module in walk_modules(name):
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 78, in walk_modules
submod = import_module(fullpath)
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\DODAAD\scrapy_goodfriday_A01\scrapy_goodfriday_A01\spiders\quotes_spider- 
checkpoint.py", 
line 33, in <module>
"execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

**NameError: name 'null' is not defined**
I don't understand what meant by name error null

Comment: Is that the indentation you have in your code? If so it is wrong

Comment: Can you show us line 33 of `C:\Users\DODAAD\scrapy_goodfriday_A01\scrapy_goodfriday_A01\spiders\quotes_spider- 
checkpoint.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Fix indents for your class:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```